# C# Functions in forms

Tags: c#, forms, function

which is the best way to create a `Function` in a `form`, so that it can be use/call in another `forms` ?

Comment: just create your function in `Form1` as `public function yourfnName().....end fucntion`

Comment: "it never works" doesn't tell us anything about what you've tried or what problems you ran into. Basically there isn't nearly enough information here for us to help you. *Why* does the method need to be in Form1? Does code in Form2 have a reference to a relevant instance of Form1? Does the method need to be an instance method?

Comment: Please assume and understand that we have no idea what `Form1`, `Form2`, and "my function" are, Questions need to include the desired behaviour and what isn't working - and @dude that isn't valid c#

Comment: You have to create an instance of Form1 in Form2, then all of the methods of Form1 are available via `form1Instance.Method();`

Answer (score 1):

Could you elaborate, show us some code for form1 and form2, what do you want to do in form2?

assuming you're creating form2 in form1 and you want to edit some text in a text box in form 2 this would be it:

```
Form from2 = new Form();
form2.textBox.Text = "new text";
```

or call a method:

```
form2.MyMethod();
```

if you don't have the instance, consider making the method in form2 `static` instead of `public`

But like i said without code i cannot help you properly for i don't know what you want.

Comment: i think this is not OP want

Answer (score 0):

declare your function as static

```
public static void name_of_function(){
//your code goes here
}
```

next to call it you just call it like this :

```
form1.name_of_function();
```

**PS :** 'void' should be changed to the type of your function , change also its name 'name_of_function to'

Answer (score 0):

You should separate your concerns, make your functions available in dedicated code classes and access them regardless of the form you're using.

That's for the sake of loose-coupling, otherwise you could make a new instance of Form1 and access its members.